# why does my client/server not working?

Tags: python, sockets

When I run the client / server together, and try to send a message, it doesn't seem like either of them recieves anything. Why?

client.py:

```
import socket, sys
import threading

# Client for WutChat #

PORT = 5000

queue = []

def exitClient(s):
    s.close()
    print "Exiting..."
    sys.exit()

def connect(host, port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try: s.connect((host, port))
    except: return "error"
    return s

def recieveData(s):
    while True:
        data = s.recv(512)
        if not data: continue
        if data in queue:
            continue
        queue.append(data)
        print data

def sendData(s):
    while True:
        try: data = raw_input(">")
        except EOFError: exitClient(s)
        if data == "": print "no msg"; continue;
        if data.startswith("/"):
            print "Command detected"
            continue
        s.send(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = connect(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))
    threading.Thread(target=recieveData, args=(s,)).start()
    threading.Thread(target=sendData, args=(s,)).start()
```

server.py:

```
import socket, sys
import threading

# Server for WutChat #

PORT = 5000
DEBUG = True

conns = {}
msgqueue = []

def connect():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try: s.bind(("", int(sys.argv[1])))
    except IndexError: s.bind(("", PORT))
    s.listen(1)

    while True:
        addr, obj = s.accept()
        conns[addr] = obj

        print str(addr)+" connected!"

        threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(addr, obj, s,)).start()


def handle(addr, obj, s):
    while True:
        try: msg = obj.recv(512)
        except:
            continue

        print msg
        msg = addr + msg

        msgqueue.append(msg)
        if DEBUG: print msgqueue

        for conn in conns:
            for message in msgqueue:
                conns[conn].send(message)
                del message

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect()
```

Comment: Due to the [excessive length](http://sscce.org/#short), this question is better suited to [codereview.sx](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have switched around the resulting tuple of [accept](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.accept):

```
addr,obj = s.accept()
```

should be

```
obj,addr = s.accept()
```

To find errors like these, remove the generic try..except block in `handle`, and catch only the specific errors you want to. In your specific case (if `obj.recv` fails), you can *catch* `socket.error`, but the only sensible thing to do when that happens is to close the socket and terminate the thread.

On an unrelated note, you may want to have a more descriptive name than `obj`. How about `client_sock` or simply `sock`?

Also,

```
msg = addr + msg
```

will fail because addr is a tuple, and msg a bytestring. You want

```
msg = repr(addr).encode('utf-8') + msg
```

Additionally,

```
del message
```

just removes the name `message`, and is a [no-op](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-op) in your case. You probably want to use [`Queue.get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get) instead.